Installing ionic deprecated packages error
I wanted to build an app using Ionic react but when I try installing the client I get the following deprecated errors:

Has anyone else been facing this issue with ionic? If so, have you found a solution?
I tried uninstalling it and then reinstalling it, nothing happened. I tried creating the react app to see if maybe it works, but no, I get this error:


Prefer copy/paste than post image of code. Also, I suggest you to [edit] your post to include the package file

sounds like you have a old node/npm version. make sure to follow the requirement section of the docs before installing: https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/environment
